# how to make multiple row of records appear as one row in a gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, entity-framework-4, group-by

Hello please have run into problems with linq to entities. Am working on a school management system.I can generate from the database the record of each student and the student scores from and this is binded to a gridview control. Below is the code i use in generating the student scores

```
    Dim subjectSearch = From subSearch In DemoSchool.EssenceSubjectRegistrations Where subSearch.Session = drpSession.SelectedItem.Text _
                    AndAlso subSearch.Term = drpTerm.SelectedItem.Text AndAlso subSearch.RealClass.ClassSN = findClassSN.FirstOrDefault AndAlso _
                     subSearch.SubjectCode = drpSubject.SelectedValue _
                     Select New With {.SubjectRegSN = subSearch.SubjectRegSN,
                                     .FirstName = subSearch.Student.FirstName,
                                     .Surname = subSearch.Student.Surname,
                                      .CA1 = subSearch.CA1,
                                       .CA2 = subSearch.CA2,
                                       .CA3 = subSearch.CA3,
                                       .CA4 = subSearch.CA4,
                                       .CA5 = subSearch.CA5,
                                       .CA6 = subSearch.CA6,
                                       .CA7 = subSearch.CA7,
                                       .CA8 = subSearch.CA8,
                                       .CA9 = subSearch.CA9,
                                       .CA10 = subSearch.CA10,
                                     .Exam = subSearch.Exam}
```

After doing this i peform this query on my result to calculate the result of some virtual columns by doing this

```
    Dim secSubjectSearch = (From jamie In subjectSearch Select jamie).ToList() _
                          .Select(Function(jamie) New With {.SubjectRegSN = jamie.SubjectRegSN,
                          .FirstName = jamie.FirstName,
                          .Surname = jamie.Surname,
                           .CA1 = jamie.CA1,
                            .CA2 = jamie.CA2,
                            .CA3 = jamie.CA3,
                            .CA4 = jamie.CA4,
                            .CA5 = jamie.CA5,
                            .MidTerm = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + jamie.CA5) / 5,
                            .CA6 = jamie.CA6,
                            .CA7 = jamie.CA7,
                            .CA8 = jamie.CA8,
                            .CA9 = jamie.CA9,
                            .CA10 = jamie.CA10,
                             .Total = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + _
                                      jamie.CA5 + jamie.CA6 + jamie.CA7 + jamie.CA8 + jamie.CA9 + jamie.CA10),
                           .Exam = jamie.Exam})
```

This result is bounded to a gridview that displays properly.My problem is that each student have three records for each subjects (subjects scores are recorded three times in a year as first term second term and third term) and this records appears as three seperate rows for each student. I want a situation where i can put each student record on only one row so that each student will have just one row in the gridview and not three rows.
I really need help from senior professionals have been pulling out my hair since the past five days. Thanks as always as you help out.

Comment: Join the terms records by student id...

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson please can you use the sample code in my question to show me how to do it. Have been trying for about 5hours now still no luck.

Comment: Not with any confidence of getting it right. Not a VB guy, and not in Linq. I'd do it in sql where it would be a lot simpler and way more comprehensible. One of the other guys should help out, when they get up.